# Latitude and Longitude using cell tower triangularization in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, location, latitude-longitude

I know how to find Latitude and longitude using the CLLocationManager class,but this needs a GPS for getting those values.But,there are also instances where GPS signals may not be recieved.

So,at that time i want to find the latitude and longitude values using cell tower triangularization method in the iPhone application is that possible.

Please anybody guide me how to implement this...

Thank you everyone

Comment: Are you aware that iOS already does this for you and hides all the gory details behind `CLLocationManager` and friends?

Comment: I am not aware of that.But,here i have a scenario like i am retrieving the lat and longt using GPS,but if i dont have GPS signals also i must able to fetch the latitude and longitude.How can i do that?

Comment: Please advise me if i am wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CLLocationManager will first use triangulation then will try to get a GPS signal.
You can't really tell whether the coordinates are based on triangulation or GPS, the vertical offset could give you information.

This is why CLLocationManager will even work on the iPad Wi-Fi only, it will try and triangulation via Wi-Fi.